# Cordova iOS: generate xcarchive file from CLI

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-cli

I was working to automate cordova build process for ios. I am able to generate .app file using 
cordova build ios --device --release

I am also able to genrate .ipa file using 
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v .. -o .. -sign......

In our project we need .xcarchive file as well. what I know is xcarchive contains .app and .DSYM file generated through 
cordova build ios --device --release

My question is can I get xcarchive file along with .ipa file.

I found few answers which genratred xcarchive file using xcbuild command. but they generates it using xcode project. I am looking if Ican get xcarchive from .app genrated by cordova build ios --device --release command.

PS: I have tried searching for similar questions, but no luck. sorry if it is duplicate. and if so please give me link.